# Search feature for cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I wanted to implement a search feature in my cakephp application.  I found this article for implementing cakephp search. 
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/search-feature-to-cakephp-blog-example

It had a google code repository found here:
http://code.google.com/p/searchable-behaviour-for-cakephp/

Things seemed to work okay until I ran into an issue trying to save a search able model from another controller.

1. Model A and Model B are search able
2. From Controller A, I call $this->Model B->save

Index fails and throws error because searchable.php behavior is trying to
use Model A as the saving Model

I posted this on the issue board of the google code page for this feature, but I have received no responses.  I figured that I would give stackoverflow a shot.

Thanks!

I do have this line in Model A and Model B
var $actsAs = array('Searchable');

These two models do no have any direct relationships

Call from Controller A
$this->Model B->create();
$this->Model B->save($this->data, array('validate' => 'false'));

Error I'm receiving
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/models/behaviors/searchable.php, line 86]

frodosghost, does this functionality work in your environment?

Comment: btw: did you see https://github.com/cakedc/search - its pretty sophisticated, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it would be around your `$this->Model B->save` call you make. Your relationships would have to be setup correctly.

I would like to see your relationships from model A to model B and also if you have the `var $actsAs = array ('Searchable');` on your model B.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relationship between those models then make sure you put Model B in your controllers $uses variable.

```
public $uses = array('ModelB');
```